# Will staying in Northern Cyprus cause problems for later travel in the EU?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, eu, cyprus, northern-cyprus

I am Peruvian, and will study in the Turkish Republic of Northern Cyprus for two years.

1. As a South American, what problems may I have if I decide to study in the TRNC, as it is recognized only by Turkey?
2. What if, having been in the TRNC, I decide to travel to the EU (Amsterdam) for summer vacations? Would I encounter any problem entering The Netherlands, a member of EU, *after* having been in the TRNC?
3. I have read that many tourists (Russians and Asians for now) are deported mostly because they go from Northern Cyprus to the Republic of Cyprus.

   Cyprus, a member of the EU, believes that those entering the country from the north are *illegal immigrants*. Does this rule apply to Cypriot internal issues only, or does it extend throughout the EU? Will it cause problems for my intended travel to Amsterdam?

Comment: Point 3 (using the land border for illegal entry) is the only one that matters.  There are no travel restrictions affecting a Peruvian national visiting the EEA other than those you would already know about.

Comment: @Nicolas, are you ok now? Do you still want somebody to come along with an answer? Or are you all set to go?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure I qualify as a newcomer anymore, but I'll make up for it with my enthusiasm for karma whoring :)

As Gayot Fow has already stated, the answers to your questions are:

1. No
2. No
3. Yes

To explain why, it boils down to the fact that **as far as the EU and the international community is concerned, the "Turkish Republic of Northern Cyprus" (TRNC) does not exist and the Republic of Cyprus (ROC) has authority over the whole island**.  [The Republic of Cyprus also believes this is true](http://www.cyprusvisa.eu/cyprus-admission-restrictions.html), and because EU citizens are allowed to travel freely in the entire territory of the ROC, they're also allowed to cross over to <s>the TRNC</s> the Turkish-occupied bits of the ROC freely.

However, if you're *not* a EU citizen, things are more complicated.  First, the ROC gets upset if you attempt to enter from the North, because in the ROC's view — and this is where we enter the bizarro-world of geopolitics — the border between the TRNC and the ROC is not *really* a border, and you've been in the ROC ever since you touched down at Ercan airport.  So if you knock on the gate of the "actual ROC" at Nicosia, and they realize you entered the "theoretical" ROC without going through ROC authorities, you're now an illegal immigrant!

What about spending long periods of time in the TRNC without ever contacting the ROC then?  If you're a European citizen, that's fine; but if you're not, you're an illegal immigrant as far as the ROC is concerned, at least in theory.  Back in reality, though, they not only have no authority over you, but they don't even know you're there, and you'll only run into potential trouble if you're silly enough to enter ROC with TRNC stamps in your passport.

Other states in the EU, though, will share the likely opinion of my fair reader at this point: *"My head hurts, make it go away."*  Which is why the Netherlands, or any EU country except maybe Greece, does not care about your TRNC stamps.

The only potential issue will be applying for the visa, as EU embassies in the ROC will likely require proof of ROC residence and embassies in Turkey will require proof of Turkish residence, and you won't have either.  Neither will they accept any proof of residence issued by the TRNC authorities, because in their opinion the TRNC doesn't exist.  So applying for the visa in your home country before you leave may be the easiest solution.

Comment: It's amusing that several of the other De Facto/De Jure territorial disputes also involve either another RoC (Republic of China) or RoK...

Comment: Great answer, and I want to confirm that it's basically only Turkey and Greece that care about this island, the rest of Europe's aspect is, quoting @jpatokal: "My head hurts, make it go away". The only thing you may need to worry about is that those two actually _do_ care about this island.

Comment: @downhand I can assure you that UK, USA and even Russia are a few of the superpowers actively trying to enforce their own political agendas on this small island. UK has 3 military bases on the island including Akrotiri which is the largest Airforce base in the Mediterranean. Russia was recently granted permission to use Cyprus military bases to support its military operations in the middle east. In a similar way US was always walking on thin line between maintaining their influence on the RoC but also keep happy their great NATO ally Turkey. This is unfortunate for the people of a tiny island.

Answer (score 7):

Traveling into Cyprus via Ercan Airport in Occupied Cyprus is against both Cypriot as well as EU law. It is not an approved port of entry into Cyprus. Getting your Passport stamped at Ercan Airport can cause issues for you when you reenter the European Union. The EU immigration folks might hastle you.

If you travel to Cyprus via Larnaca Airport in the south, you enter the country legally and you can cross over into north Cyprus via one of several approved foot paths in Nicosia. Best to do it that way, and avoid the problems.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have any references to back up your statement that an entry stamp from Ercan might cause problems when trying to enter the EU?

Comment: Google turns up a zillion package tours from the UK to Northern (Turkish-occupied) Cyprus and direct flights from Stansted to Ercan, that stop in Turkey on the way because Ercan is otherwise blacklisted. http://www.flight-cyprus.co.uk/ . Now, this allows for non-UK EU border guards to hassle you, but I doubt if you are otherwise qualified with an EU visa or are from an exempt country (e.g., USA) that they will hassle you very much. Can someone find a verified counterexample?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus "Can someone find a verified counterexample?" Nope, because it doesn't happen, and Paul is simply biased (siding with the Greeks in the Cyprus conflict). So is the EU and many member states at the diplomatic level (hence the numerous travel warnings)